# Blazor Parameter Syntax

Tags: blazor

Are there any underlying issues setting parameters using the following syntax?

```
<MyComponent MyParameter=MyValue>
```

Most examples I see use the following, using quotes and an @, but both appear to work fine.

```
<MyComponent MyParameter="@MyValue">
```

Answer (score 0):

If your MyParameter type is string, not using @ will cause your variable name to be interpreted as a literal. Apart from that there doesn't seem to be any difference. So for the sake of consistency use @.